# IIS timeout configuration

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, exe, dotnet-httpclient

I have an .exe and `webapi` projects. When I am calling the `webapi` from the .exe, the connection force fully closed around 5 mins. But I have set the timeout for `HttpClient` is 3600 seconds. If we set the timeout below 5 minutes then .exe waits till the time and will get timeout. but if we give more than 5 mins then .exe is not waiting till the time we added. Can any has any suggestion on this? in fact we tried with `HTTPWebrequest` instead `HttpClient` but facing the same problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: But why do you need a call to be around 5 minutes? For long time connections, use frameworks such as SignalR.

Comment: I am processing data file contains some 61,000 of record. After processing I am doing some operation based on the result.So I am waiting for the response